We have to count all trapezoids in the picture shown down below.

Count all trapezoids in the picture shown in link below.


I counted $76$ trapezoid until now, but I am not quite sure that is the answer.
I tried with combinatorics but the only thing that I got was dead ends. If anyone else wants to try with combinatorics I subtracted combinations without repetition for $n=25$ (every single point) and $k=4$ (number of points for quadrilateral) and number of rectangles (which is for given picture $100$).
The problem was given by my math teacher.
The definition of trapezoid here is that trapezoid is quadrilateral with only one pair of parallel sides.


Hi! I've inlined your image. Incidentally, as a minor request for future posts, could you kindly add a space after periods? It makes your posts easier to read!

Thank you for the advice. I appreciate is so much.

Hint 1:

 There are $\binom{25}{4}=12650$ ways to choose the corners. But they may not form a trapezoid that uses the edges in the given graph.

Hint 2:

 Note that the diagonals can't be part of the parallel sides used, since they have no parallel counterpart.

Hint 3:

 You can count the number of ways to select the parallel sides. We can then separately account for the trapezoids created with the help of diagonals. Consider that there is symmetry so for example those you count horizontal also appear vertically by rotating 90$^\circ$. Similarly by reflection.


I find your teacher's definition of trapezoid to be old-fashioned. Modern mathematics seems to prefer inclusive definitions, where a square is a special case of a rectangle, which is a special case of a parallelogram, which is a special case of a trapezoid.
But if we can only count trapezoids that have two opposite sides not parallel
(no rectangles!) we know that at least one of the legs of the trapezoid must lie along one of the diagonal lines.
The parallel sides must be either horizontal or vertical, since there are no other pairs of parallel lines.
We can have a trapezoid like the one in your picture, with no right angles, but there are only four such trapezoids in the figure. They should not be hard to find.
All the rest of the trapezoids will have exactly two right angles.
Let's consider the trapezoids that have horizontal parallel sides,
right angles at the right end, and a $45$-degree angle at the bottom left vertex, like this:

It should be obvious that such a trapezoid can only be found in the portion of the figure below the diagonal that runs from lower left to upper right, with its left leg lying along the diagonal.
That is, it must be somewhere in this triangular region:

Not all of the lines in even that part of the figure can be used; some of them could only be used in a triangle. But we do have several choices of lower and upper horizontal lines to use, and for each choice of upper horizontal line we have the choice of the upper right vertex, which determines the lower right vertex. (The upper and lower left vertices are on the diagonal line.)
These are things we can count combinatorially.
In a small diagram like this it's easy to count the trapezoids in the previous paragraph one at a time, but you can also make a formula that can be generalized to any number of lines in the original figure.
Now consider all the different possible orientations of the trapezoid shown above and how they would fit into the complete figure. That gives you another factor for your combinatorial counting.
Is there anything else? I don't think so.

I tried to get a formula for number of trapezoids based on what you said and I don't think I am able to do it. If you have time can you please find that formula.
